# Product Loop by a specific user role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a multi-vendor WordPress website. I would like to display products and categories added by a specific user role say "manufacturers-wholesalers". Currently using the following code to display products. Let me know is there any parameter I need to pass in the following query.
To display products I am using the following code:

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'product_cat' => 'wholesaler', 'orderby' => 'ASC' );
        ?>
```

Comment: try with this ['author__in' => 'author_id'](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: Didn't work for category listing. I need to display categories for products only uploaded by users of a particular type. Say the type is "Vendor".

Comment: can you try this : `<?php   
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 8, 
    'product_cat' => 'wholesaler', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'wholesaler',
        )),
    'author' => 'id_of_author',
    'orderby' => 'ASC'
    
    );
        ?> `

Comment: No result yet. My user role is "manufacturers-wholesalers". Need to display products only uploaded by this specific User type.

Comment: Well in above code replace the id_of_author with the id of this role manufacturers-wholesalers

Comment: How will I get the ID of that user type as I can't figure out as the id isn't coming in URL and I also check in Database.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210682/179860